# How to create a bulletlist with hyperlinks on code behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm working on an old webform application using VB.NET and I'll to create a bulleted list with in each item a hyperlink. I've tried to use three things.

### Try one

First of all I've tried to make a string of my hyperlink.

```vb
Private Sub MakeSubNavigation(lst As List(Of clsProductCategory), placeholder As PlaceHolder)

    Dim list As BulletedList = New BulletedList()

    For Each category As clsProductCategory In lst

        Dim coll As ListItem = New ListItem()
        coll.Text = "<a href=""/" & category.CategoryId & """>" & category.Name(langId) & "</a>"
        list.Items.Add(coll)
    Next

    placeholder.Controls.Add(list)
End Sub
```

This code outputs this:

[image]

### Try two

I've also tried this code:

```vb
Private Sub MakeSubNavigation(lst As List(Of clsProductCategory), placeholder As PlaceHolder)

    Dim list As BulletedList = New BulletedList()

    For Each category As clsProductCategory In lst

        Dim coll As ListItem = New ListItem()

        coll.Text = (New HyperLink() With {
            .NavigateUrl = "/" & category.CategoryId,
            .Text = category.Name(langId)
        }).ToString()

        list.Items.Add(coll)
    Next

    placeholder.Controls.Add(list)
End Sub
```

Because the `ToString()` method returns `System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink`, it doesn't work. There is no property or methode to add a control to the `ListItem` that I could use.

### Try three

This makes a list correctly but without the hyperlink *(HTML `a`-tag)*.

```vb
Private Sub MakeSubNavigation(lst As List(Of clsProductCategory), placeholder As PlaceHolder)

    Dim list As BulletedList = New BulletedList()

    For Each category As clsProductCategory In lst

        Dim coll As ListItem = New ListItem(category.Name(langId), String.Format("../{0}", category.CategoryId))

        list.Items.Add(coll)
    Next

    placeholder.Controls.Add(list)
End Sub
```

### `ascx` code

This is my code inside the `ascx` file:

```ascx
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="navigation.ascx.vb" Inherits="components_navigation" %>
<asp:Repeater ID="NavRepeater" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <ul class="list-inline">
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <li id="Item" runat="server">
      <a id="Link" runat="server">
          <asp:Literal ID="Text" runat="server" />
       </a>
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="SubNav" runat="server" /> <!-- variable placeholder in code -->
    </li>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </ul>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

### Question

My question is now: How could I add a hyperlink to a `ListItem` so that I have next output in my browser:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Bladgroenten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Koolsoorten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paddenstoelen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Peulvruchten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Stengelgroenten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vruchtgroenten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Wortel- en knolgewassen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You cant create a HyperLink inside a ListItem. The easiest way is to just create a string with all the `li` elements with their links and add it to a Literal Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a comment of @VDWWD I've tried this code and this works.

```
Private Sub MakeSubNavigation(categories As List(Of clsProductCategory), placeholder As PlaceHolder)

    Dim literal As Literal = New Literal()
    Dim builder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    builder.Append("<ul>")

    For Each category As clsProductCategory In categories

        builder.Append("<li><a href=""/")
        builder.Append(category.CategoryId)
        builder.Append(""">")
        builder.Append(category.Name(langId))
        builder.Append("</a></li>")
    Next

    builder.Append("</ul>")
    literal.Text = builder.ToString()

    placeholder.Controls.Add(literal)
End Sub
```